# I'm trying to create a javascript Dom radio button and attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a radio button using javascript. But it doesn't seem to work

```
function div()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.id = "myDiv";
    newDiv.style.width = "200px";
    newDiv.style.height = "100px";
    newDiv.style.background = "red";
    newDiv.style.border = "inset";
    newDiv.style.borderwidth = "20px";
    newDiv.style.borderColor = "blue";

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. In this case: What is your question?

Comment: i need coding for javascript radio button to create a component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `div` with `input` .And add `type="radio"`

```js
function div() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("input");
  newDiv.id = "myDiv";
  newDiv.style.width = "200px";
  newDiv.style.height = "100px";
  newDiv.style.background = "red";
  newDiv.style.border = "inset";
  newDiv.style.borderwidth = "20px";
  newDiv.style.borderColor = "blue";
  newDiv.type="radio";
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}
div();
```

***Updated***

**how to set the attribute dynamically?** 
Its same as above .[Dom element call via id](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyw4Ohn-_UAhWNYlAKHSOZDzoQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_document_getelementbyid.asp&usg=AFQjCNHDOoJUQbBS14kLimCKYChZUvSqgg)

```js
function div() {
     // var newDiv = document.getElementById("input"); //its call the element 
   //or
    var newDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
   newDiv.id = "myDiv";
      newDiv.style.width = "200px";
      newDiv.style.height = "100px";
      newDiv.style.background = "red";
      newDiv.style.border = "inset";
      newDiv.style.borderwidth = "20px";
      newDiv.style.borderColor = "blue";
      newDiv.type="radio";
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
        console.log(newDiv.outerHTML)
    }
    div();
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Comment: no bro what i'm trying to ask is how to set the attribute dynamically?

Comment: @ahmed .its same like as above .you need call the element instead of create.see my updated one

Comment: newDiv.id = "dynamically alter here"; @prasad13

Comment: yes .`id` also replaced .see my updated answer.If don't need that.try with tagname